# Java problems with overloaded constructors and exceptions

Tags: java, database, swing, exception, constructor

I am working on a task management calendar application which stores data on database and I've come across this problem. I have a main_app class which creates main swing app. it also creates an calendarDAO (Data Access Object) object which manages mySql queries, updates, etc.

Now, if something went wrong in calendarDAO I want to display error dialog message. Hence, when I create DAO object I have to give it a reference to main app. But I want to keep DAO class versatile and be able to use it without any reference to JFrame subclasses as well. So, I created overloaded constructors, one takes JFrames subclasses as a parameter and the other one doesn't (main one). Now when I call constructor which takes Jframe object I also want to call the main constructor as well so I defined it like this:

```
private MainApp mApp;

public calendarDAO(MainApp mAppRef){
    try{ 
        this(); 
    } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

     mApp = mAppRef;    
    }
```

The problem is that this would not work because my main constructor throws exception so i have to put it in try block, and now I get error saying that

> A constructor call must be a first statement in constructor

How are problems like these solved? Is my design/structure of software is wrong? help?

Comment: If the constructor is throwing an exception, why would the object be viable?  Perhaps instead of doing all the "nasty" initialisation in the constructor, maybe you need either a "factory" or a `init` method, which actually throws the exception

Comment: Also, your DAO class should know NOTHING about the UI at all EVER.  Instead, the caller to your class should be making decisions about how to handle things like the throwing of exceptions

Comment: thanks for answers, SOLVED. I was unfamiliar with term "facotry method" till today. Reading about it right away. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should throw the exception that will be thrown from both constructors

```
private MainApp mApp;

public calendarDAO(MainApp mAppRef) throws SomeExplicitException{
     this(); 
     mApp = mAppRef;    
}
```

If you are able to handle the exception then you should do what MadProgrammer suggested and create a factory method to create your object

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple observer pattern:

```
public class SimpleWorker {

    static public interface SimpleWorkerListenerIf {
        void exception(Exception pExcewption);
        // ... and more methods
    }



    private final SimpleWorkerListenerIf    mListener;

    public SimpleWorker(final SimpleWorkerListenerIf pListener) {
        mListener = pListener;
        if (pListener == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("pListener must not be null!");

        try {
            // ... some crazy stuff in here
        } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
            mListener.exception(e);
        }
    }
}
```